# Kolmogorov-Smirnov test: exact p-values for a two-sample test applied to a discrete variable when ties exist

Tags: r

I got two samples from different sites. The parameter I am interested in is discrete (frequencies). I did simulations for both sites, so I know the probabilities of a random distribution for each site. Because of my simulations I know that the deviation of my parameter from its mean is not normally distributed so I went for a parametric test. I checked with one-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov if the samples might derive from these random distributions (example data, not real):

```
sample1 <- rep(1:5, c(25, 12, 12, 0, 1))
rand.prob1 <- c(.51, .28, .111, .08, 0.019)
StepProb1 <- stepfun(0:4, c(0, cumsum(rand.prob1)), right = T)
dgof::ks.test(sample1, StepProb1)

sample2 <- rep(1:5, c(19, 13, 10, 5, 3))
rand.prob2 <- c(.61, .18, .14, .05, 0.02)
StepProb2 <- stepfun(0:4, c(0, cumsum(rand.prob2)), right = T)
dgof::ks.test(sample2, StepProb2)
```

In a next step I want to check if the samples of both sites might derive from the same distribution. Both implemetations of the KS-test (packages `stats` and `dgof`) issue a warning because my samples have ties:

```
stats::ks.test(sample1, sample2)
dgof::ks.test(sample1, sample2)
```

If I understand [Dufour and Farhat](http://ideas.repec.org/p/cir/cirwor/2001s-56.html) (2001) correctly, there is a way to calculate exact p-values through tie-breaking via Monte Carlo simulations. And if I understand the package description of the dgof package correctly, its implementation of Monte Carlo simulations only works for the one-sample test.

So my question: Does anybody know how to calculate exact p-values in R for a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test applied to a discrete variable when ties exist?

Or alternatively (though not specifically related to R): If nobody knows how to do this with a tolerable workload, I would go for the uncorrected p-values and as a consequence discuss results with care. But with p-values below 0.0001. I'm actually not overly concerned about it. But what do I know... Do you think this is right or am I making a grave mistake in this case?

Thanks in advance, I already appreciate that you read until here.

Comment: Have a look at [bootstraped KS Test](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/ks.boot.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the [function `ks.boot` of package Matching](http://sekhon.berkeley.edu/matching/ks.boot.html) implements Bootstrap Kolmogorov-Smirnov, i.e., the Monte Carlo simulation for an arbitrary number of re-samplings with the `nboots` parameter. I think that will give you what you need.

Comment: The bootstrapping has brought me into the right direction and the package seems to be well-accepted in the community, so I'll award this answer with the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the bounty. [Bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)) is one of the most powerful statistical techniques to have in your tool box. I would encourage everyone to look into it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. The mentioned package looks exactly what I was looking for. I'll definitely have a closer look into bootstrapping as well.

Answer (score 3):

Dont know whether you can apply KS here at all.
Kolmogorov-Smirnov is a **NON**-parametric test and only works for continious x and y data. I guess your sample1 and sample2 are not continuous "enough".  Quoting `?stats::ks.test`

> If y is numeric, a two-sample test of the null hypothesis that x and y
>   were drawn from the same continuous distribution is performed.

Also see:

- https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/is-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-valid-with-discrete-distributions
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test

Solution: Try to perform a Chi-Square Goodness-of-Fit Test
in `R` you do this with `?chisq.test`.
Theory can be found for example here:

- http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/chigf.htm
- http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda35f.htm

Comment: Chisq.test may not be applicable depending on the data if the values of the discrete observations are not the same in both datasets, as you need to build a contingency table first?

Comment: @ iraserd: Thants unfortunatly true

Comment: Somewhat related, [On the statistical treatment of football numbers](http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~hwainer/Readings/Frederick%20Lord_On%20the%20statistical%20treatment%20of%20football%20numbers.pdf).